# Oracle SQL compare dates less than two days old

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi guys I need your support how to perform this logic.
I'm stucking currently and i really do not know how to procide further.

Target: compare `ref_num, entry_date and status=1`

**with**

`ref_num, change_status_date, status 0 (always the last two rows)`

Compare, if these dates `change_status_date` and `entry_date` are less then 2 days old then update the status value from `status=1` to `status=2`, else If the days are more then 3 days old change to `status=0`

Any idea how to perfom a correct select sql and update sql?

```
+--------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------+
| ref_num      | entry_date            |  change_status_date | status
+--------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------+
| x326585      | 28/04/2020 16:54:14   |                     |    1     |
| x326585      | 25/04/2020 13:14:00   | 27/04/2020 23:44:00 |    0     |
| x326585      | 20/04/2020 11:15:02   | 20/04/2020 23:52:01 |    0     |

| A142585      | 28/04/2020 16:55:14   |                     |    1     |
| A142585      | 26/04/2020 11:54:04   | 27/04/2020 22:54:51 |    0     | 
| A142585      | 24/04/2020 10:44:14   | 25/04/2020 13:17:23 |    0     |

| B188532      | 29/04/2020 11:34:41   |                     |    1     |
| B188532      | 14/04/2020 11:44:24   | 15/05/2020 23:11:10 |    0     |
| B188532      | 11/04/2020 08:34:10   | 13/05/2020 11:44:41 |    0     |
+--------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------+



END RESULTS:  
+--------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------+
| ref_num      | entry_date            |  change_status_date | status
+--------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------+
| x326585      | 28/04/2020 16:54:14   | 27/07/2020 23:47:31 |    2     |  is less than 3 days (28/04/2020 16:54:14 - 27/04/2020 23:44:00) -> status 2
| x326585      | 25/04/2020 13:14:00   | 27/04/2020 23:44:00 |    0     |
| x326585      | 20/04/2020 11:15:02   | 20/04/2020 23:52:01 |    0     |

| A142585      | 28/04/2020 16:35:58   | 27/07/2020 23:47:31 |    2     |  is less than 3 days (28/04/2020 16:35:58 - 27/04/2020 22:54:51) -> status 2
| A142585      | 26/04/2020 11:54:04   | 27/04/2020 22:54:51 |    0     | 
| A142585      | 24/04/2020 10:44:14   | 25/04/2020 13:17:23 |    0     |

| B188532      | 29/04/2020 11:34:41   | 27/07/2020 23:47:31 |    0     |  is more than 3 days (29/04/2020 11:34:41  - 15/05/2020 23:11:10) -> status 0
| B188532      | 14/04/2020 11:44:24   | 15/05/2020 23:11:10 |    0     |
| B188532      | 11/04/2020 08:34:10   | 13/05/2020 11:44:41 |    0     |
+--------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

> select x.ref_num, x.entry_date, x.change_status_date, x.status from kl_table x

Thank you for your support and advice

Comment: What is the logic to set `change_status_date` to `27/07/2020 23:47:31` on every updaed row?

Comment: I *think* it is the `sysdate`, GMB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood the question.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (ref_num, entry_date, change_status_date, status) as
  2    (select 'x3', to_date('28.04.2020 16:54', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), null                                             , 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'x3', to_date('25.04.2020 13:14', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('27.04.2020 23:44', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 0 from dual union all
  4     select 'x3', to_date('20.04.2020 11:15', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('20.04.2020 23:52', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 0 from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 'b1', to_date('29.04.2020 11:34', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), null                                             , 1 from dual union all
  7     select 'b1', to_date('14.04.2020 11:44', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('15.05.2020 23:11', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 0 from dual union all
  8     select 'b1', to_date('11.04.2020 08:34', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('13.05.2020 11:44', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 0 from dual
  9    ),
```

Max `change_status_date` for that `ref_num` whose `status = 0`; it'll be compared to `entry_date`

```
 10  temp as
 11    (select
 12        a.ref_num,
 13        a.entry_date,
 14        a.change_status_date,
 15        --
 16        (select max(b.change_status_date)
 17         from test b
 18         where b.ref_num = a.ref_num
 19           and b.status = 0
 20        ) compare_change_status_date,
 21        a.status
 22      from test a
 23    )
```

Finally: I presume that `change_status_date` (that was `NULL`) should be replaced by `sysdate`. Difference between those dates should be `ABS` to eliminate negative numbers.

```
 24  select
 25    t.ref_num,
 26    t.entry_date,
 27    --
 28    nvl(t.change_status_date, sysdate) change_status_date,
 29    --
 30    case when t.status = 1 then
 31      case when abs(t.entry_date - t.compare_change_status_date) < 2 then 2
 32           when abs(t.entry_date - t.compare_change_status_date) > 3 then 0
 33      end
 34      else t.status
 35    end status
 36  from temp t
 37  order by t.ref_num desc, t.entry_date desc;

RE ENTRY_DATE       CHANGE_STATUS_DA     STATUS
-- ---------------- ---------------- ----------
x3 28.04.2020 16:54 28.07.2020 08:21          2
x3 25.04.2020 13:14 27.04.2020 23:44          0
x3 20.04.2020 11:15 20.04.2020 23:52          0
b1 29.04.2020 11:34 28.07.2020 08:21          0
b1 14.04.2020 11:44 15.05.2020 23:11          0
b1 11.04.2020 08:34 13.05.2020 11:44          0

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to *update* rows whose `status = 1`, code I posted above can be reused for e.g. `MERGE`:

```
merge into test a
     using (with temp
                 as (select a.ref_num,
                            a.entry_date,
                            a.change_status_date,
                            --
                            (select max (b.change_status_date)
                               from test b
                              where     b.ref_num = a.ref_num
                                    and b.status = 0)
                               compare_change_status_date,
                            a.status
                       from test a)
            select t.ref_num,
                   t.entry_date,
                   --
                   nvl (t.change_status_date, sysdate) change_status_date,
                   --
                   case
                      when t.status = 1
                      then
                         case
                            when abs (
                                    t.entry_date - t.compare_change_status_date) <
                                    2
                            then
                               2
                            when abs (
                                      t.entry_date
                                    - t.compare_change_status_date) > 3
                            then
                               0
                         end
                      else
                         t.status
                   end
                      status
              from temp t) x
        on (    a.ref_num = x.ref_num
            and a.entry_date = x.entry_date)
when matched
then
   update set a.status = x.status
           where a.status = 1;
```

Comment: any suggestion for the update it directly, can the same script used or you suggest something else? thx. for your great support.

Comment: Yes, it can be reused for UPDATE or MERGE. I edited my answer, have a look.

Comment: thx littlefoot i will check and come back to you asap thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will look like this.

```
update [tablename] set status=2 where DATEDIFF(day, [tablename].entry_date, [tablename].change_status_date) < 2 

update [tablename] set status=0 where DATEDIFF(day, [tablename].entry_date, [tablename].change_status_date) > 3
```

Thanks

Comment: Not likely. First of all, this is Oracle, while your code isn't. Second, you shouldn't compare dates within the row.

Comment: @usama thank you, but as mention by littlefoot this is not working on oracle.

Comment: @Littlefootdo you have a suggestion?

Comment: @James I am sorry for that.

Comment: @UsamaTahir no problem at all, thank you anyway for answering all the best